# Trying to update where clause to only apply to a certain value

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I have a stored procedure in my database. It is a dynamic piece of code and runs for multiple different parameters.

Let's say I have a parameter called `@Param` that gets passed: 17 (this parameter will be different for different processes).

In my query I am attempting to use this parameter to update the WHERE clause like this:

```
SELECT val1, val2 
FROM tbl1
WHERE 1 = 1 
  AND ((val2 IN ('h1', 'h2') AND @Param IN (17)) OR @Param NOT IN (17))
```

Does code like this make sense? I'm trying to only apply this `WHERE` clause: (val2 in ('h1','h2') to @Param=17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to want :

```
where (@param = 17 and val2 in ('h1', 'h2')) or
      (@param <> 17)
```

Comment: should this entire where clause be in a single set of paranthesis?

Comment: @Koosh . . . There is no need to overuse parentheses.  If you are more comfortable with them, then you can use them -- but like training wheels on a bicycle, they are not needed and you probably won't want to use them when you are more comfortable with SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the reason why I'm asking is i have other clauses in the WHERE statament that I want to still apply to param=17, so the statement in answer is the only code i need for this particular param